# Get KieSession and KieServices in Optaplanner

Tags: drools, optaplanner

I want to create an Audit logger for the rules i have in my OptaPlanner project
and i need to get access to KieSession and KieServices from Drools to do that.

The problem here is i don't have access to them.

In the documentation in section `5.3.4.2.3. A ksessionName in a Kjar from a Maven repository`, i can define a KieSessionName from the solverConfig and create the `SolverFactory` using the `createFromKieContainerXmlResource`. The problem here is that i can't find the `META-INF/kmodule.xml` file. Even if i find the folder, can i use the KieSessionName to get a KieSession.

I'm asking this because with the current way of creating the `SolverFactory`, using `createFromXmlResource`, i can get to the KieSessionName with using:

```
SolverConfig solverConfig = solverFactory.getSolverConfig();
ScoreDirectorFactoryConfig scoreDirectorFactoryConfig = solverConfig.getScoreDirectorFactoryConfig();
String kieSessionName = scoreDirectorFactoryConfig.getKsessionName();
```

After getting the session name i can't find a way to get the KieSession.

So my questions here are:

1. Where can i locate `META-INF/kmodule.xml`?
2. How can i use `kSessionName` to get use as a KieSession object?
3. Is there a way to access the KieSession object without chaging the core files?

Comment: It seems as you 're confusing some concepts, so it's hard for me to understand the questions. In any case, if you read `ScoreDirectorFactoryConfig.java` and manage to understand it, you'll probably be able to answer your own questions.

Comment: As i said,  as of what i have searched already and tried,  i can only locate the variable `KieSession kSession` in the `DroolsScoreDirector`, which i can't access.  Also i can get to the kieSessionName variable easy,  but i dont know how to use it to get, or even if i can get a kieSession from it.